How to create a measure that works with a Matrix with Field Parameters in PowerBI
I have 1 table and 1 field parameter table:
Table 1 we'll call MyData
Date       Employee  Store  Territory   Category    Value
1/1/2022   AAA       00     AZ          Emergency   5
1/1/2022   AAA       01     AZ          Regular     4
1/3/2023   BBB       00     NV          Emergency   4
1/8/2023   CCC       00     NV          Regular     10 

I have created a field parameter table with the fields of Employee, Store, and Territory. I have a measure that calculates the sum of Value where Category = Emergency divided by the total sum of Value for all fields. I want to be able to add a slicer for Date.  So my measures looks like this:
Numerator = CALCULATE(SUM(MyData[Value]), MyData[Category] = "Emergency")
Denominator = CALCULATE(SUM(MyData[Value]), ALLEXCEPT(MyData[Date]))
MyMeasure = DIVIDE([Numerator]/[Denominator],0)

This measure works great when I create a matrix and add the fields by which I want to view the measure.  This is an example:
Employee MyMeasure
AAA      21.74% (5/23)
BBB      17.39% (4/23)
CCC      0.00%  (0/23)

If I add a date slicer, this still dynamically changes and works based on dates selected.
The problem I face is when instead of plugging in a column such as Employee in my example, I plug in my field parameters so I can change the first column easily, the measure no longer works if I use my date slicer.  It's as if the ALLEXCEPT is ignored and treated as an ALL(Mydata) instead.
I have asked various sources and can not figure this out. I have experimented withe SWITCH() function and SELECTEDVALUES() function but to no avail.
Any and all help is appreciated.  Thank you!

You have a few syntax errors above, are they correct? I'm unable to replicate your issue with what you have provided above. Could you update your question with enough details for us to replicate please.

Can you share a .pbix with the issue?
